# Unable to fit a function onto a givin set of data points in Python using the Scipy library

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, numerical-methods

I have been trying to fit a function(the function is given in the code under the name concave_func) onto data points in python but have had very little to no success. I have 7 parameters(C_1, C_2, alpha_one, alpha_two, I_x, nu_t, T_e) in the function that I have to estimate, and only 6 data points. I have tried 2 methods to fit the curve and estimate the parameters, 
1). scipy.optimize.minimize 
2). scipy.optimize.curve_fit. 
However, I'm not obtaining the desired results i.e the curve is not fitting the data points.
I have attached my code below.

```
frequency = np.array([22,45,150,408,1420,23000]) #x_values
b_temp = [2.55080863e+04, 4.90777800e+03, 2.28984753e+02, 2.10842949e+01, 3.58631166e+00, 5.68716056e-04] #y_values

#Defining the function that I want to fit
def concave_func(x, C_1, C_2, alpha_one, alpha_two, I_x, nu_t, T_e): 
    one = x**(-alpha_one)
    two = (C_2/C_1)*(x**(-alpha_two))
    three = I_x*(x**-2.1)
    expo = np.exp(-1*((nu_t/x)**2.1))
    eqn_one = C_1*(one + two + three)*expo
    eqn_two = T_e*(1 - expo)
    return eqn_one + eqn_two

#Defining chi_square function
def chisq(params, xobs, yobs):
    ynew = concave_func(xobs, *params)
    #yerr = np.sum((ynew- yobs)**2)
    yerr = np.sum(((yobs- ynew)/ynew)**2)
    print(yerr)
    return yerr

result = minimize(chisq, [1,2,2,2,1,1e6,8000], args = (frequency,b_temp),  method = 'Nelder-Mead', options = {'disp' : True, 'maxiter': 10000})
x = np.linspace(-300,24000,1000)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.plot(x,concave_func(x, *result.x))
print(result.x)
print(result)
plt.plot(frequency, b_temp, 'r*' )
plt.xlabel("log Frequency[MHz]")
plt.ylabel("log Temp[K]")
plt.title('log Temparature vs log Frequency')

plt.grid()
plt.savefig('the_plot_2060.png')
```

I have attached the plot that I obtained below.
[image]

The plot clearly does not fit the data, and something is definitely wrong. I would also want my parameters alpha_one and alpha_two to be constrained to lie between 2 and 3. I also do not want my parameter T_e to exceed 10,000. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need at least as many data points as you have parameters, else the system is underdetermined. The error code or error message should indicate such, just print `result.message` or `result` in full.

Comment: Hi, I did check “result.message” and it says “Optimization Terminated Successfully”. Also, I do understand that the system is underdetermined which is why I used Nelder - Mead.

Comment: It sometimes helps to set the error tolerances. Perhaps also try out the `curve_fit` procedure.

Comment: I changed the initial guess from `1E6` to `1E2` and it worked relatively well. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, Thanks for the suggestion. Since the function was a very pathological, curve_fit did not do the trick. I will check it out once again.

Comment: @K.Cl Thank you very much, it did work! Why was it so sensitive to the initial conditions? Can I add bounds to the parameters when using Nelder-Mead?

Comment: Nelder-Mead is overrated. It works nicely in 2D demonstration cases and when the function is strongly convex, but has no proven behavior outside these cases. Similar is of course true in general, convergence proofs are usually local, to get convergence you need to start close enough to the solution. Methods for global convergence are heuristic, they amount to intelligent random guesses. There are some methods in the middle like trust-region methods.